# new Layout or adding anything to existing layout it is not getting auto-inserted into R.java file

Tags: android, layout, r.java-file

`Home.xml` in layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.52"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`R.java` class

```
 public static final class id {
        public static final int action_bar=0x7f05001c;
        public static final int action_bar_activity_content=0x7f050015;
        public static final int action_bar_container=0x7f05001b;
        public static final int action_bar_overlay_layout=0x7f05001f;
        public static final int action_bar_root=0x7f05001a;
        public static final int action_bar_subtitle=0x7f050023;
        public static final int action_bar_title=0x7f050022;
        public static final int action_context_bar=0x7f05001d;
        public static final int action_menu_divider=0x7f050016;
        public static final int action_menu_presenter=0x7f050017;
        public static final int action_mode_close_button=0x7f050024;
        public static final int action_settings=0x7f050048;
        public static final int activity_chooser_view_content=0x7f050025;
        public static final int always=0x7f05000b;
        public static final int beginning=0x7f050011;
        public static final int btnLinkToLoginScreen=0x7f050047;
        public static final int btnLinkToRegisterScreen=0x7f050041;
        public static final int btnLogin=0x7f050040;
        public static final int btnRegister=0x7f050046;
        public static final int checkbox=0x7f05002d;
        public static final int collapseActionView=0x7f05000d;
        public static final int container=0x7f05003c;
        public static final int default_activity_button=0x7f050028;
        public static final int dialog=0x7f05000e;
        public static final int disableHome=0x7f050008;
        public static final int dropdown=0x7f05000f;
        public static final int edit_query=0x7f050030;
        public static final int end=0x7f050013;
        public static final int expand_activities_button=0x7f050026;
        public static final int expanded_menu=0x7f05002c;
        public static final int home=0x7f050014;
        public static final int homeAsUp=0x7f050005;
        public static final int icon=0x7f05002a;
        public static final int ifRoom=0x7f05000a;
        public static final int image=0x7f050027;
        public static final int listMode=0x7f050001;
        public static final int list_item=0x7f050029;
        public static final int loginEmail=0x7f05003d;
        public static final int loginPassword=0x7f05003e;
        public static final int login_error=0x7f05003f;
        public static final int middle=0x7f050012;
        public static final int never=0x7f050009;
        public static final int none=0x7f050010;
        public static final int normal=0x7f050000;
        public static final int progress_circular=0x7f050018;
        public static final int progress_horizontal=0x7f050019;
        public static final int radio=0x7f05002f;
        public static final int registerEmail=0x7f050043;
        public static final int registerName=0x7f050042;
        public static final int registerPassword=0x7f050044;
        public static final int register_error=0x7f050045;
        public static final int search_badge=0x7f050032;
        public static final int search_bar=0x7f050031;
        public static final int search_button=0x7f050033;
        public static final int search_close_btn=0x7f050038;
        public static final int search_edit_frame=0x7f050034;
        public static final int search_go_btn=0x7f05003a;
        public static final int search_mag_icon=0x7f050035;
        public static final int search_plate=0x7f050036;
        public static final int search_src_text=0x7f050037;
        public static final int search_voice_btn=0x7f05003b;
        public static final int shortcut=0x7f05002e;
        public static final int showCustom=0x7f050007;
        public static final int showHome=0x7f050004;
        public static final int showTitle=0x7f050006;
        public static final int split_action_bar=0x7f05001e;
        public static final int submit_area=0x7f050039;
        public static final int tabMode=0x7f050002;
        public static final int title=0x7f05002b;
        public static final int top_action_bar=0x7f050020;
        public static final int up=0x7f050021;
        public static final int useLogo=0x7f050003;
        public static final int withText=0x7f05000c;
    }
```

HomeActivity

```
package com.prgguru.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.prgguru.example.R;
/**
 * 
 * Home Screen Activity
 */
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Displays Home Screen
        setContentView(R.layout.display);
    }

}
```

I have downloaded a sample android project from net, and when I try to edit or add a `textview` or anything to the existing xml file in layout, nothing gets updated in `R.java`.Therefore could not access the elements or the newly created layout in Activity classes.Please help me, as I do not have any clue why it is happening.

Comment: delete R.java file and clean the project. R.java vll generate again

Comment: if i delete R.java , How will it generate again? I mean do I have to make the project run as Android appliaction

Comment: Delete `R.java` and then clean the project.

Comment: nope. delete the R.java file and go to project > clean and check in your bin folder.. new r.java file will create

Comment: I have deleted R.java. and gone to projects->clean .On doing so errors in my Activity class saying"R cannot be resolved to a variable, and there is no R.java in gen folder.please help

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions, but nothing really helped me. So, I have create a new application, in there everything works fine, the R.java file is taking all the entries,

Comment: but my query remain answered friends, in the existing application, which I have downloaded, The R.java File did'nt got updated..